# Static Linking Cursive/ncurses in Rust

Tags: linux, rust, static-linking

I am trying to create a statically linked executable for a rust project that uses Cursive (with ncurses as backend). I installed the libraries for ncurses-devel, ncurses-static, ncurses-lib as well as did

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

When I try to compile the project using:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

cargo fails with the error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ncurses v5.101.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/vagrant_data/rust-cli-example/target/release/build/ncurses-9d002170cebb3401/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=NCURSESW5_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=NCURSESW_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=ncursesw
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-musl")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")

  --- stderr
  /vagrant_data/rust-cli-example/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ncurses-7d3468c31a087559/out/chtype_size.c:6:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
      6 | #include <ncurses.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: command.status().expect(\"compilation failed\").success()', /home/vagrant/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ncurses-5.101.0/build.rs:105:5
```

Can someone please guide me in what needs to be done to get this to compile?

Comment: you need to have headers of ncurses in your system

Comment: Headers are there in /usr/include on my system. I am able to statically link a C program with ncurses so it does not look like something related to ncurses but something more rust specific

Comment: @SaptarshiKar Just in case, you haven't found a solution to this?